# Outlook addin On Send on dektop not firing

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have been building an office add-in for Outlook.

I have a taskpane, that works fine, and yesterday, I added "on send" function.

It works well on web, but it doesn't work on desktop.
Mails are just sent without any notification message.
According to the documentation, it should work on desktop now?

*"The on-send feature is currently supported for Outlook on the web in Exchange Online (Office 365), Exchange 2016 on-premises (Cumulative Update 6 or later), and Exchange 2019 on-premises (Cumulative Update 1 or later). This feature is also available in the latest Outlook builds on Windows and Mac, connected to Exchange Online (Office 365). The feature was introduced in requirement set 1.8."*

I am using:

- Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11929.20436) 32-bit
- Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1903

I have done the step "[manage the on send policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows#manage-the-on-send-policy)" too.
Is there anything else I am missing? Do I need to do some special settings to make it work on desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THanks for your post Tom, good question. This is a problem of you not having the Office build that supports the OnSend Feature in Windows.

The cited article is accurate in the sense that the feature is avialable in the "Latest Outlook Builds in Windows". To be more specific, this means 16.0.12130.20272+ builds. At the time of this writing, the onSend feature is only avialable in the Office 365 Monthly subbscription. We need to improve that document and thats a follow up in my team, I agree it might lead to confusion.

It seems, by your build number,  that you are in the Semi-Annual Subscription, 1.8 will be on the next Semi-Annual Channel release, not yet released.

So you have 2 options.
1. EIther you [install the latest Insiders fast](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join) (to test your code)
2. Wait around July 2020 for the next Semi Annual release.

Hope this helps, btw for future reference this page can guide you to see requirement set avialability https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I have installed Insider level Monthly Channel, and it works now on outlook desktop too.