# Outlook Javascript Add-In: "ItemSend" Event doest trigger on outlook for windows, why?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I created an outlook plugin that i'm testing on local enviroment.
the plugin is working when user is composing new message.
I have a function that is supposed to be triggered on item send.

The thing is that the event us not triggering only for outlook on windows:

1. "outlook for the web" - **Works fine!**
2. Outlook for mac - **Works fine!**
3. Outlook for windows - **doesnt work!!** (event doesnt trigger)

Heres my xml event:

```html
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
    <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack" />
</ExtensionPoint>
```

I tested it even in vorlon debuggger
and i see my console log when the add-in is lunched, but not when item is sent,
(heres my code and a screen shot to see that the office.onReady is doing console.log('9999') , but "checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack" function in not doing console.log()):

```js
  Office.onReady(function(reason){ 
    mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    console.log('9999')
  });
  
  function checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack(event) {
    console.log('vvvv')
  }
```

[image]

this is my outlook version on windows:
[image]

**ANY HELP?**

Comment: To quote an earlier answer by Juan Balmori, 
"The feature is avialable in the 'Latest Outlook Builds in Windows'. To be more specific, this means 16.0.12130.20272+ builds. At the time of this writing, the onSend feature is only avialable in the Office 365 Monthly subbscription. We need to improve that document and thats a follow up in my team, I agree it might lead to confusion.  It seems, by your build number, that you are in the Semi-Annual Subscription, 1.8 will be on the next Semi-Annual Channel release, not yet released."
Earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902376/6147663

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlook addin On Send on dektop not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60891055/outlook-addin-on-send-on-dektop-not-firing)